# Debugging PHP server

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Help!!! I know nothing about php and the lead programmer for the online hackathon we are in needs the php server by the morning. The submission needs to be ready on repl.it

> Error:
>   172.18.0.1:50190 [500]: / - Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /home/runner/LuxuriousEnragedRoutes/db.php:2
>   Stack trace:
>    #0 /home/runner/LuxuriousEnragedRoutes/index.php(3): require_once()
>    #1 {main}
>   thrown in /home/runner/LuxuriousEnragedRoutes/db.php on line 2
>   0 Comments

Comment: It could be that the mysqli extension isn't installed on the server.

Comment: it can be so many things. We are not clairvoyant...

Comment: Could someone be willing to help? I could send the entire file

Answer (score 0):

please install mysql extension

in centos php72u-mysql  for php7.2
sudo yum php72u-mysql -y
in debian or ubuntu php-mysql 
sudo apt install php-mysql